# "Could not write to TensorArray index 0 because it has already been written to." why not?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So usually the problem is that indexes can only be read once unless clear_on_read is false. But I haven't come across this error yet "Could not write to TensorArray index 0 because it has already been written to.".

```
def bod(i, centroids, base, seq, thres):
    eu_dist = tf_sqrt(tf_reduce_sum(tf_square(tf_subtract(base,centroids[i])), axis=1))
    argmin = tf_cast(tf_argmin(eu_dist), tf_int32)
    default_write = tf_constant([0,0,0], tf_int32)
    seq = tf_cond(tf_less(eu_dist[argmin], thres), lambda: seq.write(i, centroids[i,argmin]), lambda: seq.write(i, default_write))
    return i, centroids, base, seq, thres

def find_sequence(centroids, thres = 1.0):
    centroids_tf = tf_placeholder(tf_float32, shape=(3,None,3))
    base_tf = tf_placeholder(tf_float32, shape=(3))
    thres_tf = tf_placeholder(tf_float32)
    i_tf = tf_constant(0, tf_int32)
    seq = tf_TensorArray(tf_float32, size=(tf_shape(centroids_tf)[0]), )
    con = lambda i, cen, base, seq, thres_: tf_less(i, tf_shape(centroids_tf)[0])
    i, centroids_out, base_out, part, thres_ = tf_while_loop(con, bod, [i_tf, centroids_tf, base_tf, seq, thres_tf])
    part_seq = part.stack()

    object_seq = []
    with tf_Session() as sess:
        for cent in centroids[0]:

            seq_out = sess.run(part_seq, feed_dict={centroids_tf: centroids[1:], base_tf: cent, thres_tf: thres})
            append = True
            for s in seq_out:
                if s == [0,0,0]:
                    append = False
                    break
            if append:
                object_seq.append(seq_out)
    return object_seq
```

Can anyone help? or tell me how I can get around it?

Comment: Shouldn't `bod` end with `return i + 1, centroids, base, seq, thres`?

Comment: Haha, well thx I totally overlooked that ;)